# I'm trying to make an alarm clock (from a tutorial) in Python, Playsound isn't activiting sound

Tags: python, python-playsound

I'm trying to make an alarm clock, and it works for the most part. But I installed playsound so I could make it play music when it goes off as an alarm clock should. I'm not quite sure how to use paths and even when I place the .wav in the folder it's meant to be it doesn't play.
Code:

```
import datetime
from playsound import playsound

alarmHour = int(input("What hour do you want to wake up?"))
alarmMinute = int(input("What minute do you want?"))
amPm = str(input("Am or Pm")).lower().strip()

if (amPm == "pm"):
    alarmHour = alarmHour + 12

while(1 == 1):
    if(alarmHour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and
       alarmMinute == datetime.datetime.now().minute):
     print("Wake up, lazy!")
     playsound("C:\\Users\\wicke\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\askaway.wav")
     break

print("Exited")
```

The error:

```
Error 275 for command:
        open "C:\Users\jeandae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\askaway.wav"
    Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct.

    Error 263 for command:
        close "C:\Users\jeandae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\askaway.wav"
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
Failed to close the file: "C:\Users\jeandae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\askaway.wav"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jeandae/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/alarm 2.py", line 16, in <module>
    playsound("C:\\Users\\jeandae\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\askaway.wav")
  File "C:\Users\jeandae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 72, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand(u'open {}'.format(sound))
  File "C:\Users\jeandae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 275 for command:
        open "C:\Users\jeandae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\askaway.wav"
    Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct.
```

Comment: Include your code as ***text*** in the body of the question. In line with [ask], this makes it much easier for potential answerers to see where you may have run aground in your efforts to make your code work. (On top of that, it's much less effort/clicks to include it as text rather than an image.)

Comment: Consider simplifying your code to the minimal example that demonstrates your problem.  You say your issue is that the `playsound` isn't playing a sound.  Consider simplifying your code to just import `playsound` and call it instead of the rest of the code that complicates reasoning about if and how many times `playsound` is actually called.

Comment: Some things to try: Does calling the playsound function directly, without any of the other code work? does playsound('file_that_does_not_exist.wav') produce the same behavior or does it crash? Is your volume on and the sound you're playing loud enough to hear?

Comment: Are you sure the file is in the correct folder?  you are not calling a folder explicitly so, depending on how you run the code, it will look in one of many folders to find the .wav file

Comment: @KyleParsons  When I try to run it on it's own I get a long ass error. From what I'm reading a misplacement could certainly be the issue but I have no idea where I'm meant to place it.

Comment: @Keon , no, no it does not. To either one of your questions. My volume is indeed on and loud enough to hear, and thank God because as long as I've been trying to figure this out I'd hate myself if it wasn't.

Comment: @JeffUK ,I'm pretty sure? I gave it the exact location AND tried moving it directly to a python directory. But maybe the wrong one. I put it in /AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/ for a test or two. I've tried it was askaway.wav and as ask away.wav

Comment: @SebSebSeb please edit the post to include the long ass error

Comment: @Keon So about that, it goes past character limits

Comment: Can you post the start/end of it? You can also edit your post rather than post it in the comments, which will give a longer character limit

Comment: @Keon, I edited the text body. Uhh. It formatted a bit weird and I'm not sure why

Comment: "Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct." is the important part here. The things after it are related errors that happen because that original error. Is your sound file actually in `\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\ `? If it isn't, change the path to the correct one. If it is, it might be a permissions thing (python might not be able to see that folder). In that case, try playing a file from a more normal place like `C:\Users\jeandae\Music` or something?

Comment: @keon I've tried it from music and I've trid it from Desktop. Also, thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Give the play sound function the absolute path of the audio file ex:

```
playsound('C:/Users/user/Desktop/away.wav')
```

Comment: If I do that I get this I get a long long error

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with that package if you want you can use [pydub](https://pypi.org/project/pydub/) which is more reliable than playsound.

Your code is okay and the problem is with the playsound it is not playing the audio. A very easy way to do so is.

```
import datetime

from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

alarmHour = int(input("What hour do you want to wake up?"))
alarmMinute = int(input("What minute do you want?"))
amPm = str(input("Am or Pm")).lower().strip()

if (amPm == "pm"):
    alarmHour = alarmHour + 12

while(1 == 1):
    if(alarmHour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and
       alarmMinute == datetime.datetime.now().minute):
     print("Wake up, lazy!")
     file1= AudioSegment.from_file("audiofile.wav")
     play(file1)
     break

print("Exited")
```

But you need to install pydub and you might face some error i recommend you read this article to properly install [pydub](https://www.alixaprodev.com/2021/08/create-sounds-with-python-package-pydub.html).

Comment: Thanks big time! I'll update you when I test it. For a good bit I was feeling like an absolute idiot.

Comment: SO. I download it, wrote this code from pydub import AudioSegment
from 

pydub.playback import play

sound = AudioSegment.from_file("C:\\Users\\wicke\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\pydub\\__pycache__\\askaway.wav"), format="wav")
play(sound)

I get the "cannot assign to function call"

Comment: You have to write code as follows. Note that if you put the file in your current project directory you do not have to specify the relative path. just write the name of the file which is present in the current directory.

from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

sound = AudioSegment.from_file("audiofile.wav", format="wav")
play(sound)

Comment: Even whenever I do that I get invalid syntax. At first I thought it may be the space between play and sound, but then when I remove that it just says the = is the syntax issue. I'm surprised how hard such a simple thing is to pull off in coding